# How to import Access 2007 to SQL Server through Import Wizard?

Tags: sql-server, import

**Is there a way to get around this problem?** (through GUI)

Currently SQL Server 2005/2008 do not allow me to import Access 2007 database as shown below
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help: http://www.online-tech-tips.com/ms-office-tips/ms-access-to-sql-database/

Comment: @Lukaz: Thanks for the link.  It was as simple as converting Access 2007 to 2003 before import